# Классы C++: проблемы с работой конструктора

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, что у меня в программе неверно. Компилироваться она не хочет, не могу понять причину. Жду помощи! Спасибо.

```
#include <string.h>   
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>
#include <fstream>
#include <clocale>

class data  
{      
  int day;  
  int year;  
  public:   
  data (int a, int b)// конструктор  
  {
     day=a;
     year=b;
   }
  void age(int, int);  
  int readday()   
    {return day;};  
  int readyear()   
    {return year;}

};  
int main()  
{
 (LC_ALL,"Russian");  
  data Kate (02, 1991);
  int d, y;
  d=Kate.a; // подскажите пожалуйста, что неверно в это строчке и как надо!!!
  y=Kate.b
  getchar();  
  getchar();  
  return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (LC_ALL,"Russian");

Тут только список аргументов, а где имя функции?

```
data Kate (02, 1991);
```

Убери нолик перед числом. Он означает, что ты передаёшь число в восьмеричной системе счисления, а ты вряд ли этого хотел. В данном случае, 02 и 2 равны, но если ты попробуешь написать 08 или 09, то получишь ошибку компиляции, так как цифр 8 и 9 в восьмеричной системе не существует.

```
d=Kate.a; // подскажите пожалуйста, что неверно в это строчке и как надо!!!
y=Kate.b;
```

a и b - это параметры, передаваемые в конструктор при создании объекта. Доступ к ним имеет только конструктор. Он их копирует в day и year. Только они скрыты, и к ним нельзя обращаться напрямую. У тебя уже есть методы для их чтения - readday() и readyear(). Итак, исправленный код:

```
d=Kate.readday();
y=Kate.readyear();
```

Советую тебе начать изучать классы сначала. Твои ошибки говорят о том, что ты эту тему не понял.

Answer (score 3):

1. Не определен конструктор.
2. Не определена функция age
3. функция getchar() требует включения заголовка cstdio или stdio.h

**P.S.**

Конструктор можно определить очень просто. В теле класса пишите:

```
data (int a, int b) {day=a; year=b;}
```

Или вне тела класса (но нужно сохранить объявление):

```
data::data (int a, int b) {day=a; year=b;}
```

Comment: конструктору тоже нужен прототип, как остальным функциям?..

Comment: Если Вы его не определяете, то создается дефолтный конструктор. Но если Вы его объявили (а именно это Вы сделали), то нужно его определить.

Answer (score 2):

Может потому, что Вы не реализовали конструктор, а всего лишь его объявили!? :)

Comment: поясните, пожалуйсте. как он реализовывается?

Comment: В 2ух словах всех тонкостей не обьяснить, очень кратко - так-же как и для функций - любой прототип должен иметь определение. У вас есть прототип, определения нет

Comment: К справедливым замечаниям уважаемых коллег хотелось бы добавить следующее:

1. Несмотря на простоту инициализации экземпляра Вашего класса считается хорошим тоном объявлять хотя бы пустой деструктор virtual ~data(){;}

2. Почти всегда бывает полезным объявлять также конструктор по умолчанию для создания массива объектов, конструктор копирования; а также прегрузить операторы operator= и operator[]

Comment: Какая перегрузка операторов! Тут еще азбуку не освоили.

Comment: @mikillskegg. То, что я перечислил в п.2 - это тоже азбука. В противном случае, класс практически бесполезен.

Comment: Ну, по сути это все правильно. Про деструктор, может, уже пора услышать человеку. Но про перегрузку еще рано. А то совсем запутается.

Comment: И кстати, можно просто ~data() {}

Comment: BuilderC: а оператор [] зачем?

Comment: Это оператор для индексации массива объектов типа Т. Например:
class TMatrix
{
  private:
 int line, col;
   double **m;
  public:
    double* operator [](const int i)const {return m[i];}

Comment: >1.Несмотря на простоту инициализации экземпляра Вашего класса считается хорошим тоном объявлять хотя бы пустой деструктор virtual ~data(){;}

 Никакой деструктор не нужен. Удалять нечего, а деструктор по умолчанию не зря сделали. Я прочитал кучу книг по написанию качественного кода и нигде не было написано, что нужно объявлять пустой деструктор. Только если предполагается наследование, и классы-наследники получат какую-то логику освобождения ресурсов. Классу data это не грозит.

 operator= и конструктор копирования по умолчанию делают то, что должны.